# How to get payment receipt after payment done from RevenueCat in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

I am implementing RevenueCat first time in my react native. I have one non-renewable subscription available on App Store. and now I want to buy that subscription by revenueCat sdk.

The payment is successfully happening at my and but I have to validate receipt again at my backend so I need the payment receipt.

How can I get the payment receipt while doing the payment from the revenueCat.

Here is code which I am following to do the payment by revenueCat.

```
if (!subscriptionModule) {
  if (constant.isIOS) {
    Purchases.setDebugLogsEnabled(true);
    Purchases.setup('appl_TTTTTTTTTTTTTTT');
    console.log('sdk initialized');
  }
}
async getOffer() {
  try {
    const doubleJoinProduct = await Purchases.getOfferings();
    if (
      doubleJoinProduct.current !== null &&
      doubleJoinProduct.current.availablePackages.length !== 0
    ) {
      console.log('the offer list is = ', doubleJoinProduct);
        if (
          doubleJoinProduct.all['com.pozzleplanet.test.doubleJoinMonth']
            .availablePackages.length !== 0
        ) {
          let inapp_package =
            doubleJoinProduct.all['com.pozzleplanet.test.doubleJoinMonth']
              .availablePackages[0];
          console.log('The available package is = ', inapp_package);
          this.purchaseProduct(inapp_package);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error while getting offer', e);
    }
  }
  async purchaseProduct(inapp_package: any) {
  console.log('package purchasing....', inapp_package);

  try {
    const purchaseMade = await Purchases.purchasePackage(inapp_package);
    console.log('before purchase info is = ', JSON.stringify(purchaseMade));
    if (
      typeof purchaseMade.purchaserInfo.entitlements.active[
      'com.pozzleplanet.test.doubleJoinMonth'
      ] !== 'undefined'
    ) {
    console.log('purchase info is = ', JSON.stringify(purchaseMade));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('the purchase error is ', e);
  }
}
```

Can some please suggest me to get payment receipt

Comment: revenue cat is just a wrapper around the platform native in app purchase APIs.  You can obtain the receipt in the same way as you would if you weren't using revenue cat.